# Is there a way to split a literal string to multiple lines with out enter to it \r

Tags: c#, string-literals

In my code i got a very long and complicated string that I want to save as a literal string 
At the moment my line is 1200 character long.
And I want to separate the lines in the way which every line it wouldn't be longer than 200 characters

```
string comlexLine = @"{""A"": {""B"": [{""C"": {""D"": {""E"":""+"" ""/F;
```

I would like to separate it into shorter lines so the code would be more readable.

At the moment when I enter a new line, because it is a literal string a **\r** is entering to the string

for example:

```
string comlexLine = @"{""A"": {""B"": "
                     + "[{""C"": {""D"": {""E"":""+"" ""/F;
 Console.WriteLine(comlexLine);
```

would print:

```
 @"{""A"": {""B"": //r "[{""C"": {""D"": {""E"":""+"" ""/F
```

I prefer not to split it to different constant and also to use a literal string.
Is there any solution?

Comment: How about to put your line in resource file?

Comment: If you split the string over two lines you have two options: Split the string into two strings and concatenate with `+`, this will not add a linefeed to the string. Use the literal string syntax, `@"..."` and split it inside, this will add a linefeed inside. Those are your options.

Comment: Your example with the `+` in it won't add a newline, nor does it compile. Can you clarify what your problem with that statement is? It seems to me that you already know how to solve this.

Comment: Yes. I see that the people that comment here not fumiler with literal strings. Its a kind of a string that what ever you write - for example jump a line it inserts it to the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Environment.NewLine` instead for including a new line in your string. i would rather make it like below using a back slash `\` to escape the extra double quotes

```
string comlexLine = "{\"A\": {\"B\": " + Environment.NewLine + "[{\"C\": {\"D\": {\"E\":\"+\" \"/F";
Console.WriteLine(comlexLine);
```

Comment: I just want a more clean code in the way each line is less than 200 characters

Answer (score 1):

Try not using the literal and escaping the double quotes with a slash.

```
string comlexLine = "{\"A\": {\"B\": [{\"C\": "
+ "{\"D\": {\"E\":\"+\" \"/F";
```

If I use that, it doesn't introduce the //r.

Comment: you cant add "+" to a literal string without changing it. literal string is "literal" and will add everything that you write to the string